# Save text added to textbox in DOM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

I have a website that saves the entire DOM using PHP and Jquery:

```
urldecode($_POST[$('html').html()))
```

Works great, and saves everything that is in the DOM...except what is entered into a textbox.

Is there a way to force textbox input/value in the DOM so that the following will also capture that input?

```
$('html').html()
```

Comment: It's generally not a very good idea to save the entire DOM, but instead create methods that save the changed data only, for instance placing form elements inside a form, and just submit the form etc.

Comment: Do you mean a textarea? If so, it's $('#id_of_textarea).val()

Comment: Before you save you could do something like `$('input').attr('value', function() { return this.value; });`, although I have to ask, *why* are you doing this?

Comment: @Rory Almost the entire site is created dynamically, with each user having their own personal site. I find saving the entire DOM much easier than writing individual values to the DB.

Comment: Really? I've created similar systems before and have always used a DB as a datastore. How are you intending to handle basic design changes?

Comment: @Gearman I see that that would get the value...but how can this be forced into the DOM?

Comment: Rory's solution should work fine, whenever a property is changed, like a `value`, force it to set the attribute as well.

Comment: I tried Rory's solution but when I reload the site, the text that was added to the input is not there

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

**Code Changes :**

**HTML :**

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txtval" />
<input type="button" value="Save text in DOM" id="btnval" />
</body>
</html>
```

**JQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnval').click(function(){
            $("#txtval").attr('value',$("#txtval").val());
                console.log($('html').html());
        });
    });
```

Jsfiddle Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/xj7c31eh/